# Importing a figure drawn in inkscape with equations in latex

Tags: latex, inkscape

I am trying to import a figure in latex which is drawn in inkscape. The figure contains some mathematical notations which are written in latex compatible format. For example, if there is notation for acceleration in x-direction ax, I wrote in inkscape figure like $mathbf{ax}$. But when I try to import this figure in Latex, it gives an error 'missing $ inserted'. Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome @ SO.com! Please provide us a minimal (not) working example which represents your tryings! (Also: what is the file type you save by `Inkscape`?)

Comment: tex.stackexchange.com may be better suited